# How to compare two excel sheets list?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets list both has the same data which is first name and last name. I want to know if list A has the same last name, and the first 3 character from first name from list B. I tried to use Vlookup function but I did not work. I want to match exact last name and exact three character from first name.

Answer (score 1):

An example:

`Worksheet 1`

```
     A      B
1    John   Smith
2    Jane   Jones
3    Robert West
```

`Worksheet 2`

```
     A      B            C
1    John   Smith        MATCH
2    Jane   Jones        MATCH
3    Bob    West         NO MATCH
```

In cell `C1` on `Worksheet 2` enter this formula as an *array formula*:

`=IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,3),B1),CONCATENATE(LEFT(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3,3),Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3),0))),"MATCH","NO MATCH")`

Drag your formula down to include cells `C2` and `C3`.

*Notes*

1. To enter as an array formula use `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`
2. Update the `Left` formula to match different numbers of characters in first name